# heat equation on half-infinite intervals change of variable

Tags: calculus, partial-differential-equations

I want to solve the heat equation on half-infinite interval:
$$\begin{cases}
  \displaystyle u_t=u_{xx}  \;x>0,\:t>0 \\
  \displaystyle u(x,0)=\phi(x) \; x>0\\
  \displaystyle u(0,t)=0
\end{cases}$$
I know I can solve this equation below
$$\begin{cases}
  \displaystyle u_t=u_{xx}  \;x \in \mathbb{R},\:t>0 \\
  \displaystyle u(x,0)=\phi(x) \; \\
  \displaystyle u(0,t)=0
\end{cases}$$
The solution is given by:
$$H_t(x)*\phi(x)$$ 
where $H_t(x)=C \frac{\exp(-x^2/(4t))}{\sqrt{t}}$ is the heat kernel, C is some constant

So I define:
$$\phi_{odd}(x)=\begin{cases}
  \displaystyle \phi(x) \;\;x\geq 0\\
  \displaystyle -\phi(-x) \;\;x< 0\\
\end{cases}$$
I know $H_t*\phi_{odd}$ solves the second equation, write it explicitly, I get:
\begin{align}
 u(x,t)&=C\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{\exp(\frac{-(x-y)^2}{4t})}{\sqrt{t}}\phi_{odd}(y)dy \; \\
&=C\int_{-\infty}^{0}\frac{\exp(\frac{-(x-y)^2}{4t})}{\sqrt{t}}\phi_{odd}(y)dy+C\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{\exp(\frac{-(x-y)^2}{4t})}{\sqrt{t}}\phi_{odd}(y)dy\\
&=C\int_{-\infty}^{0}\frac{\exp(\frac{-(x-y)^2}{4t})}{\sqrt{t}}(-\phi(-y))dy+C\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{\exp(\frac{-(x-y)^2}{4t})}{\sqrt{t}}\phi(y)dy\\
\end{align}
How do I use substitution to re-write the first term, so that I can merge two integrals into one?

Use $z=-y$ and $dz=-dy$

the first term =$C\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{\exp(\frac{-(x-y)^2}{4t})}{\sqrt{t}}(-\phi(z))(-dz)$=$C\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{\exp(\frac{-(x-y)^2}{4t})}{\sqrt{t}}\phi(z)dz$
But my answer is not correct for the substitution part, why?(there should be a minus sign)

Answer (score 1):

Replace $y$ by $-y$.

So it becomes,

$$\int_{\infty}^0\frac{1}{\sqrt t}\exp\left(-\frac{(x+y)^2}{4t}\right)(-\phi(y))(-dy) = -\int_0^\infty\frac{1}{\sqrt t}\exp\left(-\frac{(x+y)^2}{4t}\right)\phi(y)dy$$

Comment: why the first equation is from $\infty$ to 0 not otherwise?

Comment: We've replaced y with -y. So when y is $-\infty$ , -y is $+\infty$

Comment: I see... So we never swap upper limit and lower limit when doing change of variable?